# Docker container running on localhost:8000 but unable to connect to localhost:8000 via browser?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've a docker container running on port 8000 but can't connect to localhost:8000 via browser.

I've added the port mapping properly and my server is able to start and connect to postgres db.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16.15-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start-dev" ]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=iclasspg
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  iclassbe:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - DB_PASSWORD=iclasspg
      - DB_SCHEMA=postgres
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_HOST=postgres
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_SSL=false
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
```

I'm **using WSL** on Windows to run my containers.

Comment: Do you reach you container with ```curl localhost:8000``` from WSL Terminal?

Comment: @m19v Nope, I get: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused`

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.wslconfig` file in your home folder, set `localhostForwarding` to `true` and restart `wsl`

```
[wsl2]
memory=4GB
swap=0
localhostForwarding=true
```

[Working with Docker on Windows](https://dev.to/grawl/working-with-docker-and-other-unix-things-on-windows-like-on-macos-or-linux-4o6p)

[Advanced settings configuration in WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-global-options-with-wslconfig)

Comment: It should be noted that `true` is the default value, so unless it was explicitly set to `false` for some reason, that won't change anything.

Comment: @W.S. tried but that didn't help, still getting the same issue.

Comment: What does `docker port CONTAINER` returns? (check your container name by `docker ps`) https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/

Comment: And on your windows host machine what's the output of `wsl hostname -i`? It should return the ip address of your wsl instance. Try to access with that ip address (`IP_ADDRESS:8000`)

Comment: `wsl hostname -i` gives `127.0.1.1` but browser is unable to connect to `127.0.1.1:8000`.

Strangely, `docker port <iclass_be_container_name>` doesn't give any result, the prompt just returns back, but it gives correct port for the postgres  container name. 
I also checked the container running in my Docker Desktop and;
`postgres container` is running and is on `PORT 5432`, also, 
`iclass (nodejs server)` container is running, but there is no port number displayed

Comment: Also, doing `docker container ls -a` gives `0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::543` under the `PORTS` column for `postgres` container but just `8000/tcp` for my `nodejs container`.

Comment: I figured out the problem, my `8000/tcp` port was't being bound, this was because I wasn't using the `--service-ports` flag in my docker-compose command. Thanks, for pushing me towards the solution.